# How to batch write to nested collection in Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having trouble implementing a batch write to my Firestore via Cloud Functions.

Background: This is a personal project developing a Chrome extension for a Wordle leaderboard.

Here's the intent of my cloud function:

1. Make a request for the Wordle solution
2. Add a "contest" document to the contests collection within each leaderboard document
   2a. The path to the document looks like: /leaderboards/{leaderboardDocId}/contests/{contestDocId}

And here's my cloud function code:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const https = require('https');

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

functions.cloudEvent('getWordleSolution', () => {  
  const incrementAndPad = (num) => {
    const str = String(num + 1);
    return str.padStart(2, "0");
  }

  const now = new Date();
  const year = now.getUTCFullYear();
  const month = incrementAndPad(now.getUTCMonth());
  const date = now.getUTCDate();

  const url = `https://www.nytimes.com/svc/wordle/v2/${year}-${month}-${date}.json`;
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    let puzzleData = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => puzzleData += chunk);
    res.on('end', () => writeToFirestore(JSON.parse(puzzleData)))
  })

  const writeToFirestore = async ({ id, solution, print_date }) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const batch = db.batch()

    const leaderboardsRef = db.collection('leaderboards');
    const leaderboardDocsSnapshot = await leaderboardsRef.get();

    leaderboardDocsSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const leaderboardRef = snapshot.ref;
      const contestsRef = leaderboardRef.collection('contests');
      batch.set(contestsRef.doc(id), { solution, print_date });
    })

    await batch.commit()
  }
});
```

Of note:

- The 'contests' collection may not exist on a leaderboard doc. I'm hoping this function will create the collection in the event it doesn't exist
- The code above doesn't throw any errors in the console. It simply doesn't write to the Firestore.

Thanks for reading!

I tried getting a reference to all docs in the leaderboards collection, looping through each to add a contest document to a nested contests collection via batch, then executing the batch. The code did not throw errors but did not write to the Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an official way to do this but I would use `Promise.all` to just update them all at once like this:

```
const writeToFirestore = async ({ id, solution, print_date }) => {
   let promises = [];
   const db = admin.firestore();
   const leaderboardsRef = db.collection('leaderboards');
   const leaderboardDocsSnapshot = await leaderboardsRef.get();

   leaderboardDocsSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const leaderboardRef = snapshot.ref;
      const contestsRef = leaderboardRef.collection('contests');
      promises.push(contestsRef.doc(id).set({ solution, print_date }));
   });
   return await Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Heres the docs for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: The code in my original post works as intended. I overlooked an error in the logs caused by the contest document id being a number instead of a string. Converting the `id` value passed to `writeToFirestore` to `String(id)` produced the intended result.